# [Mapbox-Android]How can I show all the shops,hospitals near users location?

Tags: java, android, location, mapbox, mapbox-android

There is a tutorial: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-store-locator/
This shows how to manually add our shops, creating a dataset and show that in our app. I want to get all the hospitals, banks near a specific user location. How can I achieve this? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the Mapbox Tilequery API to query the `building` layer of Mapbox Streets or query your own custom style that has bank/hospital data.

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/overview/tilequery/

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/examples/tilequery/

Use https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/tilequery/ to play with the Mapbox Tilequery API. For example, https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8/tilequery/-122.4052,37.7564.json?limit=19&radius=536&layers=building&dedupe=true&access_token=PASTE_YOUR_MAPBOX_TOKEN_HERE gives you a `FeatureCollection` of `Feature` objects. Loop through each `Feature` to see whether it's `type` property is `hospital`, `bank`, etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3xFN.jpg

Regarding using the device's location to use for the Tilequery request:

Set up the `LocationComponent` as seen in https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/show-a-users-location . Then you can do the following to get the device location:

```
locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLatitude();
locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLongitude();
```

Or if you need to track the device location:

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-location-listening

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/location-change-listening

Comment: is there any way to specify in query to get `FeatureCollection` of only specified `Feature` type?

Comment: You can query a specific map layer. You'll be a given a list of `Feature`s. You could parse through the list to look for `Feature`s with a certain property type or something.

Comment: Yeah thats what I have been doing. The thing is that I want to show the nearest hospitals given any location. So, in my case I queried `poi_labels` layer and went through loop. But, the first 50 results didn't have hospitals, although I set the the radius long enough(there were many hospitals in that radius). So now, I was looking if I can specify in query directly that I need feature of type `Hospital` so that I would only get list of hospitals in the result.